# How to reload MySQL 8 and update SSL certificates

Tags: linux, mysql, service

What is the correct way to update MySQL 8 SSL certificates without having to restart the service?

With PostgreSQL, you can do a reload using "systemctl reload postgresql", for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to restart the service you can simply use this command in `mysql`

```
flush privileges;
```

It will reload the SSL certificates and updates the SSL configuration